# mod_expires.c and mod_headers.c not working according to google pagespeed insights

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, apache2.4, mod-expires, mod-headers

When running a test on [google pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnoram.dk%2F) I get the error "Leverage browser caching"

### What I have done

1. Confirm that modules are enabled and working in Apache.

   As you can see here: http://noram.dk/phpinfo.php both `mod_expires` and `mod_headers` are installed and enabled. Also when i write `sudo a2enmod expires` and `sudo a2enmod headers` I get a "module already enabled" (And I did restart Apache2)
2. Double confirm that modules are enabled and working in Apache.

   To double check this I have also tried removing the `<ifModule mod_expires.c>` and `<ifModule mod_headers.c>` lines from my .htaccess file (and the end tags ofc.), to confirm that I can still load the page without getting a server. I have also confirmed that my .htaccess file is working, by writing some junk in it, which does kill my website. (i also have working RewriteRule's in it)

### So to summarize

1. I am pretty sure the modules are installed and running.
2. The htaccess file is working and being read by the server.
3. I have inserted the code in the htaccess file as I should.

However, I keep getting the same feedback from google PageSpeed insights.

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I can't post my whole htaccess file :(  To long for reply and stackoverflow claims it has links in it so I cant post it in the msg.

Comment: You should not leave open your phpinfo.php, the best option is to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do anything more. The results are as such because of

```
http://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-98431.js?sv=5 (60 seconds)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

since, none of those files are hosted on your own machine, you do not have control on their expiry headers. They will be cached as defined by the servers `static.hotjar.com` and `google-analytics.com` respectively.